# ctypes pointer to a c_int vs array of c_ints

Tags: python, arrays, pointers, ctypes

I'm trying to call a function in a dll. The function is called `pop()` and takes two parameters, an int and a pointer to an int. The first parameter is the length of the array that starts at the second parameter. This function should return a pointer to an int that is the first element in an array of `n-1` elements where `n` is the number of elements in the original array. The returned array should be the original array, without the 0th element.

**My code:**

```
from ctypes import cdll, c_int, POINTER

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('extlib.dll')

lib.pop.restype = POINTER(c_int)
#lib.pop.restype = c_int*4

testArray = (c_int*5)(*[5,6,7,8,9])
output = list(lib.pop(5, testArray)[0:4])

print output
```

When ran as is, it produces the following (expected) output:

```
[6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If I uncomment the commented line, and comment the line above it, I get this (unexpected) output:

```
[6618688, 0, 2, 0]
```

It appears that the types `c_int*4` and `POINTER(c_int)` are different, as I believe that is all I changed. However, [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#type-conversions) seems to suggest that they should be the same. What is going on here? Specifically, why don't the two versions of the code perform the same?

Comment: 64-bit Windows and/or Python?

Comment: Both 64 bit Windows and Python

Comment: I'm guessing it comes down to pointers and arrays aren't actually the same things in C, even if they are very similar.

Comment: Try using `c_void_p` or `c_longlong` instead of `c_int` as they should be pointer sized on 64-bit Windows (`c_int` is still 32-bits).

Comment: @figs c_void_p and c_longlong both give different and undesired output. I also tested c_long and c_short, which likewise give an undesired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> platform.architecture()
('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
>>> ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_int*4)
16
>>> ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
8
```

Clearly, these are different entities. Specifically, an array cannot be returned from a C function since it doesn't fit into a register.

In the 2nd case, your result is your returned `int*` saved somewhere by `ctypes` and interpreted as `int[4]`: the 1st is your pointer, further are some garbage at the following addresses. On x64, the 1st is one DWORD of the address, the next is the other DWORD (which is which depends on your endianness), the rest are garbage.